# NSNumber timestamp in milliseconds to NSDate

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSNumber with a value of 1369605600000.

The value is a timestamp in milliseconds that I want to convert into an NSDate. I tried converting it with `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` but i dont know how to divide the NSNumber by 1000 to convert it to seconds first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [aNumber doubleValue] / 1000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
```